# GIF loaded in a Service using Glide only shows first frames

Tags: android, service, imageview, gif, android-glide

I have an app where when a user opens a link pointing to an image, instead of opening the browser, a floating `ImageView` is created inside a `Service`and shown above all the other apps (which requires `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission). Here is a link to the app: [Tappic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.dmoral.tappic).

I want to add animated GIF support using Glide (I have also tried other libraries, but the result is always the same) but only the first frames of the GIF are shown, then it stops.

Here is the code where I load the image inside the `Service`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    dataString = intent.getDataString();
    if (dataString != null)
        Glide.with(this).load(dataString).into(tooltipImage);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

You can view a [video hosted in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MadpLYkUuHMGhna2FoOE9TN0k/view?usp=sharing) showing what's the problem.

As you can see **it does work** if I move the View around the screen. Here is the code handling the movement (`tooltipContainer` is the layout containing the `ImageView`):

```
tooltipImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private int initialX;
    private int initialY;
    private float initialTouchX;
    private float initialTouchY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX + (int) (motionEvent.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY + (int) (motionEvent.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(tooltipContainer, params);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I don't know where is the problem making the GIF animation work.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tested Glide, Picasso, and Fresco for animated GIFs on a personal project. Glide correctly loaded the animated GIF maybe 50% of the time for me. Many times it also added some image artifacts and/or skipped frames.

Out of the three, Fresco actually worked flawlessly for animated GIFs - fast load times, low heap memory overhead, and I haven't seen any artifacts yet. Give Fresco a shot, it might be that Glide can't properly display your GIF.